# How to find the subset of common items in two bags using Apache Pig?

Tags: apache-pig

I want to find the subset of common items (=intersect) in two lists using Apache Pig.

In SQL, the accepted way would be to use inner join, e.g.:

```
C = SELECT * FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.name=B.name;
```

However, with all the advanced options in Pig (like DIFF, DataFu's SetIntersect), I am not sure that it is the best way (in terms of performance, MapReduce paradigm, etc).

So the following two options would work - but what is the best practice?

Option A:

```
grouped = COGROUP A BY name, B by name;
common = FOREACH grouped {
A1 = ORDER A BY name
B1 = ORDER B BY name
GENERATE SetIntersect(A1,B1);};
```

Option B:

```
grouped = COGROUP A BY name, B by name;
common = FOREACH grouped {
GENERATE SetIntersect(A.name,B.name);};
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: best practice depends on the size of your data. In general avoid ordering.

Comment: Why would you not just do an inner join in Pig?

Comment: If I understand correctly, each inner join will start a new MapReduce procedure - which might be costly (especially if multiple such checks are required). So I am wondering if there's a better way to do that than SQL-style joining.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your relations have the same schema, or you are only interested in one field (e.g. Name), I can suggest an approach which will be much faster than SQL-style JOIN for very large files

```
a = LOAD 'Afile.txt' using PigStorage() as (name:chararray);
b = LOAD 'Bfile.txt' using PigStorage() as (name:chararray);
a_counters = foreach a generate *, 1 as from_a, 0 as from_b;
b_counters = foreach b generate *, 0 as from_a, 1 as from_b;
united = union a_counters, b_counters;
res = foreach (group united by name) generate group, SUM(united.from_a) as from_a, SUM(united.from_b) as from_b;
res = filter res by from_a >=1 and from_b>=1;
```

res will now contain only the names which are in both files. This generates a single MR job. For my huge files (billions of rows, tens of fields) this approach finishes in minutes, compared to hours when I use JOIN.

This approach will create an indicator for each record, denoting which file it came from. Then you 'concatenate' the two files, and sum the indicators per name. Names which exist only in file A will have from_a >= 1, and from_b == 0. Names which exist only in file B will have from_b >= 1, and from_a == 0. Names existing in both files will have from_a >=1 and from_b>=1.